# Generics type. All calls go to the same method and I don't know why

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, inference

I have some problems with generic types. I don't understand why in this code 
all the calls to myTest point at:

```
public static <MyData> void myTest(Integer integer)
```

In some cases I specify the type between angle brackets:

```
tr.<Number>myTest(null); OR tr.<String>myTest(null);
```

But I expect that calls go to other methods.

this is my class:

```
public class MyTest {

    public static void main(String[] arg){
        MyTest tr = new MyTest();

        tr.<Number>myTest(null);

        tr.<MyTest>myTest(null);

        tr.<String>myTest(null);

    } 

    public static <Number> void myTest(Number number){
    }
    public static <MyData> void myTest(Integer integer){
    }
    public static           void myTest(String string){
    }
    public static <String> void testClass(String string){
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm. If it's ambigious, the code should not even compile.

Comment: `<Number>` makes a type variable called `Number`. It's no longer referring to `java.lang.Number`. Just remove the `<Number>`. (Similarly for other methods).

Answer (score 2):

```
public static <Number> void myTest(Number number){
}
```

Here, `<Number>` creates a type variable called `Number` - you are no longer referring to `java.lang.Number`. This code is semantically equivalent to writing:

```
public static <T> void myTest(T number){
}
```

so it's basically the same as writing

```
public static void myTest(Object number){
}
```

(assuming you never need to refer to `Number`/`T` in the body of the method).

As such, all three of the method invocations

```
tr.<Number>myTest(null);
tr.<MyTest>myTest(null);
tr.<String>myTest(null);
```

are simply invoking the same method with different generic constraints.

If you want a different method for each type, don't use generics. Just define a non-generic overload for each of the types:

```
void myTest(Number n) { ... }
void myTest(MyTest n) { ... }
void myTest(String n) { ... }
```

and then invoke with an explicit cast of the `null` (or a reference of the particular type):

```
myTest((Number) null);
myTest((MyTest) null);
myTest((String) null);
```

Comment: Then which is the use for <T>? If I put "Number", I want to say "Object", If I put Integer, I want to say "Object", etc... I read java documentation and I understand that you can call to any method without <T>. I think that is not right but all says my that <T> is useless... :( I need to clear this. Thanks.

Comment: You use type variables when you need to constrain the type. For instance, one use case is where you need two (or more) variables to be of the same type: `<T> void myTest(T paramA, T paramB) {}`. Another is where you need the return type to match a param: `<T> T myTest(T param) { return param; }`. Another is where you need to place a bound on the type: `<T extends Number> void myTest(T someNumber)`. Another is where you actually need to refer to type in the body.

Comment: Ok. here I difference for the parameters: 
 `tr.myTest(new String ("A"), new String("B"));
 tr.myTest(new String ("A"), new Integer("1"));
 tr.myTest(new String ("A"), null);
 tr.myTest(new Integer("1"), new Integer("1"));
 <T> void myTest(T paramA, T paramB){
     }
 <T> void myTest(String paramA, T paramB){
 }
 <T> void myTest(String paramA, String paramB){
 }
 <T> void myTest(Integer paramA, T paramB){
 }
 <T> void myTest(Integer paramA, Integer paramB){
 }`
Then isn't very often write `tr.<Number>`. right?
Is more frequent use the parameter's types to discriminate the method called, right?

Comment: I found this:  The complete syntax for invoking this method would be:

`boolean same = Util.<Integer, String>compare(p1, p2);`
The type has been explicitly provided, as shown in bold. Generally, **this can be left out** and the compiler will infer the type that is needed:**

`boolean same = Util.compare(p1, p2);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a new variable and then call your method with it. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
     MyTest tr = new MyTest();

     Number number = null;
     tr.<Number>myTest(number);

     MyTest mTest = null;
     tr.<MyTest>myTest(mTest);

     String str = null;
     tr.<String>myTest(str);
}
```

Comment: I just understand the use for "tr.<Number>" or " tr.<MyTest>" or "tr.<String>", I don't have any example in which the use of "tr.<>" is usefull...